# Connection Firebird DB via SSH

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, firebird, ssh-tunnel

I am creating an application with Laravel and Firebird 2.5 and wants to run it on a DigitalOcean server structure. We have 2 servers for the application, one for the web services (lets call it www) and one for the database services. I did a successful setup with Mysql and it works well but we all know Firebird is a rough one. So this is what we did so far: 
Install a LEMP stack in www and Firebird 2.5 SuperServer. As I said these are digital ocean servers, both runs Ubuntu 14.04. 
We created an SSH tunnel between the two server with the following structure:

```
ssh -L 9500:127.0.0.1:3050 username@db_server_ip_address (Private address)
```

But when we tried to hook up the application on www with the database server got the following error:

> unavailable database

In the Laravel Configuration file used the following set up:

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=/home/username/database.gdb
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

The credentials are correct, we can use it on the remote (db) server.

What do you think what could be the problem? Is it the SSH tunneling?

Comment: This sounds more like a sysadmin or DBA question than a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

Warning: I don't use SSH that much, and have never used SSH tunneling, my answer is based on looking at documentation.

The `ssh -L 9500:127.0.0.1:3050` does not do what you think it does:

> Specifies that connections to the given TCP port or Unix socket on the local (client) host are to be forwarded to the given host and port, or Unix socket, on the remote side. This works by allocating a socket to listen to either a TCP *port* on the local side, optionally bound to the specified *bind_address*, or to a Unix socket. Whenever a connection is made to the local port or socket, the connection is forwarded over the secure channel, and a connection is made to either *host* port *hostport*, or the Unix socket *remote_socket*, from the remote machine.

(from [ssh(1)](http://man.openbsd.org/ssh))

In other words, as far as I can tell the proper command would be:

```
ssh -L 9500:<ip-address of the Firebird server>:3050
```

The second problem seems to be that your Laravel config does not specify a port, so it is likely still trying to connect to port 3050 (the Firebird default port), instead of port 9500 that you configure. I don't know Laravel, but a property `DB_PORT=9500` seems logical (but maybe these properties are specific to your own deployment, in which case you may need to do some more work).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think the best way would be OpenVPN then.

Comment: @Gabesz I'm unsure what part of my answer leads to that conclusion.